# Not able to map SuperClass with a nested Object, while mapping child class

Tags: java, mapstruct

I am trying to map classes using MapStruct. I have Super class and child class extending it. The fields are mapped correctly in BaseMapper generated code, but in the ChildMapperImpl, the fields from Parent are not mapped and missing.

Class and Mapper code are below:

```java
@Data
@SuperBuilder
public class BaseDTO {
  private Long id;
  private FullNameDTO name;
}
```

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
public class BaseEntity {
  private Long id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
}
```

```
@Data
@Getter
public class FullNameDTO {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
}
```

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
public class ChildDTO extends BaseDTO{
  private String childName;
}
```

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
public class ChildEntity extends BaseEntity{
  private String childName;
}
```

Mapper for Base Classes:

```
@Mapper
public interface BaseMapper {
  @Mapping(target = "name.firstName",source = "firstName")
  @Mapping(target = "name.lastName",source = "lastName")
  BaseDTO toDTO(BaseEntity entity);
  BaseMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(BaseMapper.class);
}
```

Mapper for Child classes:

```
@Mapper(uses = BaseMapper.class)
public interface ChildMapper {
  ChildDTO toDTO(ChildEntity entity);
  ChildMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(ChildMapper.class);
}
```

The fields are mapped correctly in BaseMapper, but in the ChildMapper, the fields from Parent are not mapped and missing.

ChildMapperImpl:

```
public ChildDTO toDTO(ChildEntity entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        ChildDTO.ChildDTOBuilder<?, ?> childDTO = ChildDTO.builder();

        childDTO.id( entity.getId() );
        childDTO.childName( entity.getChildName() );

        return childDTO.build();
    }
```

If I have primitive type for firstName and lastName in BaseDTO, instead of custom object, fields are getting mapper correctly.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BaseMapper is not a `@Mapper`, is a `@MapperConfig`

```
@MapperConfig
public interface BaseMapperConfig {
    
    @Mapping(target = "name.firstName", source = "firstName")
    @Mapping(target = "name.lastName", source = "lastName")
    BaseDTO toDTO(BaseEntity entity);
    
}
```

and the ChildMapper has to use the BaseMapperConfig as configuration, and on the method level, you need to add the @InheritConfiguration

```
@Mapper(config = BaseMapperConfig.class)
public interface ChildMapper {
    
    ChildMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(ChildMapper.class);
    
    @InheritConfiguration
    ChildDTO toDTO(ChildEntity entity);
    
}
```

the generated mapper will be:

```
public class ChildMapperImpl implements ChildMapper {

    @Override
    public ChildDTO toDTO(ChildEntity entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        ChildDTO.ChildDTOBuilder<?, ?> childDTO = ChildDTO.builder();

        childDTO.name( childEntityToFullNameDTO( entity ) );
        childDTO.id( entity.getId() );
        childDTO.childName( entity.getChildName() );

        return childDTO.build();
    }

    protected FullNameDTO childEntityToFullNameDTO(ChildEntity childEntity) {
        if ( childEntity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        FullNameDTO fullNameDTO = new FullNameDTO();

        fullNameDTO.setFirstName( childEntity.getFirstName() );
        fullNameDTO.setLastName( childEntity.getLastName() );

        return fullNameDTO;
    }
}
```